# Spring boot tries to create class deleted from project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea, repository

**I have deleted one of the `Components` from project:**

```
    @Component
    public interface ClientRepo extends CrudRepository<Client, Integer> {
    }
```

**and I have changed `Client` class from `Entity` to `Embeddable`**

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Embeddable
    public class Client {
      @NotNull
      @Size(max = 200)
      private String email;
      @NotNull
      @Size(max = 200)
      private String phoneNumber;
   }
```

**Here I use this `Client` class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEETINGS")
public class Meeting extends BaseEntity {

  @Embedded
  private Client client;
}
```

*And this is what I get when I try to start the project:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given domain class does not contain an id attribute!
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build directory? For maven it's called "target".

Comment: @Jakubeeee that was it, thanks :)

Comment: I suggest you that you use Repository instead of Component, has some of functionality on repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an answer based on my comment:
When you delete or rename a class from your project be sure to clean your build directory to get rid of its compiled .class equivalent. If you are using maven, you can do it by calling **clean** command or by removing **target** directory manually.

Comment: I was looking for a solution for this for ages. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No "**ClientRepo**" is needed, as the "**client**" class is annotated by *@Embeddable*, all its columns will be added within the "**meeting**" class on the database.

This means, no table called "**client**" will be generated and created by the JPA in your database.

Therefore, you have to remove definitely "**ClientRepo**" and use instead "**MeetingRepo**"